# Class File for org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestIterationListene not found

Tags: java, maven, jmeter

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:(87, 20) java: cannot access org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestIterationListener
  class file for org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestIterationListener not found
```

I don't know why. Here is some info about the problematic code:

Imports:

```html
import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.ResponseAssertion;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.SetupThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
```

The Function that is causing this Error:

```html
private HTTPSampler createHttpSampler(String method, String host, int port, String path){
    HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
    httpSampler.setMethod(method);
    httpSampler.setDomain(host);
    httpSampler.setPort(port);
    httpSampler.setPath(path);
    return httpSampler;
}
```

My J-Meter-Dependencies inside my Pom.xml

```html
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_http -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Do you guys maybe know what causes this problem? Is there any way to check which Dependency I have to add to get

```
org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestIterationListener
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the error is caused by so called [jar hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) when different JMeter libraries are relying on different dependencies versions which clash somewhere somehow.

Is there any specific reason for having JMeter libraries from **3 different versions**? According to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) you should be always using the latest version of JMeter, which is [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) as of now so consider amending your dependencies to look like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
  <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
  <version>5.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_http -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
  <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
  <version>5.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_java -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
  <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
  <version>5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also consider adding the next lines to your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler creation:

```
httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
```

This will allow you to open the generated Test Plan in JMeter GUI.